# Measuring time with OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es-3.0

Is it possible to measure the GPU time with OpenGL ES 3.0? With OpenGL, I could use glQueryCounter, but OpenGL ES doesn't have time queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, not in the core specification, but check out this extension: [EXT_disjoint_timer_query](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_disjoint_timer_query.txt). If that's what you want, extension support can be queried by passing `GL_EXTENSIONS` to `glGetString`.